# Custom UINavigationBar with custom height in center

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I have reviewed almost all questions on OS related to custom `NavigationBar` but unable to find those solutions helpful. Please have a look on following screenshot,
[image]

Red portion represents an icon (small image) in the center of navigationBar.

Please suggest some solution. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I want to implement that for all `UINavigationBar` in app. I mean on each view

**NOTE:** I do not know who is down voting my question but i want to ask a question from those persons. Do you have any solution for my problem? If not, then why you are down voting my question? I will not be able to get help in this way. It's totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass UINavigationBar.

```
#import "VSNavigationBar.h"


@interface VSNavigationBar ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *noseView;

@end


@implementation VSNavigationBar

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    static CGFloat width = 80;
    if (!_noseView) {

        UIView *noseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2 - width / 2, 0, width, width)];
        self.noseView = noseView;

        self.noseView.backgroundColor = self.barTintColor;
        self.noseView.layer.cornerRadius = self.noseView.frame.size.width / 2;

        [self addSubview:_noseView];
    }
    _noseView.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2 - width / 2, 0, width, width);
}

@end
```

And in your Storyboard you would select the NavigationController scene, in the tree view on the left select Navigation Bar and on the right side select the identity inspector and change the class to the subclass.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: BTW: I honestly and deeply hate those designs.

Comment: What about logo (icon) in the center of that nose view ?

Comment: it is a view, so you can add any subview.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an image that looks like central part of the image you have provided and say -

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo.png"];
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
self.navigationItem.titleView = image view;
```

If you are trying to get circular effect like the bottom of the image you provided, in that case you need to have same image as above and set it as background image of navbar -

```
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"yourImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Not working, also I want to implement it for all `UINavigationBar`